# Navigation stack Holonomic: true not working

Tags: ros, navigation, stack, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Though i set navigation stack holonomic parameter to true it doesn't generate y velocity. Any suggestions

I am using ROS indigo and Ubuntu 14.04.

Thank you

**EDIT:**
Here are the launch files & output of roswtf:

**base_local_planner_params.yaml**

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  acc_lim_th: 3.2
  acc_lim_x: 2.5 
  acc_lim_y: 2.5 
  max_vel_x: 0.65 
  min_vel_x: 0.0 

  max_vel_y: 0.1 
  min_vel_y: -0.1 

  max_trans_vel: 0.65 
  min_trans_vel: 0.1 
  max_rot_vel: 0.5 
  min_rot_vel: 2.0 
  sim_time: 1.7 
  sim_granularity: 0.025 
  goal_distance_bias: 32.0 
  path_distance_bias: 24.0 
  occdist_scale: 0.01 
  stop_time_buffer: 0.2 
  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05 
  forward_point_distance: 0.325 
  scaling_speed: 0.25 
  max_scaling_factor: 0.2 
  vx_samples: 3 
  vy_samples: 10 
  vtheta_samples: 20 
  sim_period: 0.1 
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2 
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.17 
  rot_stopped_vel: 0.01 
  trans_stopped_vel: 0.01
  holonomic_robot: true
  y_vels: [-0.6, -0.1, 0.1, 0.6]
```

**Costmap_common_params.yaml**

```
obstacle_range: 1
raytrace_range: 1.5
footprint: [[-0.2,-0.2],[-0.2,0.2], [0.2, 0.2], [0.2,-0.2]]
#robot_radius: ir_of_robot
inflation_radius: 3

observation_sources: scan

scan: {sensor_frame: /laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

**global_costmap_params.yaml**

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_link
  update_frequency: 1.0
  publish_frequency: 0.5
  static_map: false
  transform_tolerance: 1.5
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 100.0
  height: 100.0
```

**local_comstmap_params.yaml**

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: /base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05
  transform_tolerance: 1.5
  planner_frequency: 1.0
  planner_patience: 5.0
```

**Output of roswtf**

```
WARNING: Package "ompl" does not follow the version conventions. It should not contain leading zeros (unless the number is 0).
WARNING: Package name "twist_Converter" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits and underscores.
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /mavros:
   * /mavros/setpoint_raw/global
   * /mavros/setpoint_raw/attitude
   * /mavros/setpoint_velocity/cmd_vel
   * /mavros/setpoint_position/local
   * /tf_static
   * /mavlink/to
   * /mavros/rc/override
   * /mavros/setpoint_raw/local
   * /mavros/setpoint_accel/accel
 * /move_base:
   * /tf_static
   * /move_base/cancel
 * /rviz:
   * /tf_static


Found 1 error(s).

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /move_base->/move_base (/move_base/global_costmap/footprint)
 * /move_base->/move_base (/move_base/local_costmap/footprint)
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed to DWA local planner. It too doesnt output linear y velocities.

Edited move_base.local

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find my_robot_name_2dnav)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
   
   <rosparam command="load" file="$(find  my_robot_name_2dnav)/dwa_local_planner_params.yaml"  />
     <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />
  </node>
   
</launch>
```

dwa_local_planner_params.yaml

```
DWAPlannerROS: 
   acc_lim_th: 3.2 
   acc_lim_x: 2.5 
   acc_lim_y: 2.5 


   max_vel_x: 0.65 
   min_vel_x: 0.0 

   max_vel_y: 0.65 
   min_vel_y: -0.1 

   max_trans_vel: 0.65 
   min_trans_vel: 0.1 
   max_rot_vel: 1.0 
   min_rot_vel: 0.4 
   sim_time: 1.7 
   sim_granularity: 0.025 
   goal_distance_bias: 32.0 
   path_distance_bias: 24.0 
   occdist_scale: 0.01 
   stop_time_buffer: 0.2 
   oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05 
   forward_point_distance: 0.325 
   scaling_speed: 0.25 
   max_scaling_factor: 0.2 
   vx_samples: 3 
   vy_samples: 10 
   vtheta_samples: 20 
   sim_period: 0.1 
   xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2 
   yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.17 
   rot_stopped_vel: 0.01 
   trans_stopped_vel: 0.01
   holonomic_robot: true
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227474/navigation-stack-holonomic:-true-not-working/) by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2016-02-24**:
Please provide launch file. Also include the output of `roswtf`

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2016-02-24**:
Velocities should be generated regardless of holonomic option.

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-02-24**:
Thanks for the response @asagitov. I have edited my question to provide launch files and roswtf.

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-02-24**:
Also @asagitov I do get velocities as output. The nav stack runs fine. However right now i guess any motion suggested by planner is rotate-> move in x -> rotate. What i want is planner to suggest "y vel" which i guess is the property of holonomic constraints

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2016-02-25**:
Try changing `y_vels: '-0.6, -0.1, 0.1, 0.6'` to `y_vels: [-0.6, -0.1, 0.1, 0.6]`. Maybe it is just syntax error.

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-02-25**:
Hey @asagitov I tried that too. it doesnt work yet. Any other thing that i may be doing wrong?

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2016-02-26**:
Looks like local planner decided that is inefficient to move in y plane. Try raising max_vel_y. Also you can try using DWA planner if you are using base_local_planner and vice versa.

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-02-29**:
Thanks @asagitov. will try that out

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-03-05**:
@asagitov I tried using DWA local planner. It too doesnt output y velocities. i have updated my question with dwa files.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-03-05**:
@automate I have a DWA config that works for me. Meaning the robot is exhibiting lateral motion (sometimes). I'll post the contents of my `YAML` file in a couple of hours. Please ping me if I seem to have forgotten.

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-03-05**:
sure @spmaniato. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Give this DWA configuration a try (changing the numbers to fit your robot). It results in lateral motion (when the corresponding trajectories end up having lower cost of course). Many of the parameters below won't affect your issue, but I've copy-pasted my exact config just in case.

```
base_local_planner: "dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS"

controller_frequency: 10.0      # 20.0
controller_patience:  15.0      # 15.0

DWAPlannerROS:

  holonomic_robot: true

  # Tolerances                  Defaults
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.05      # 0.05
  xy_goal_tolerance:  0.05      # 0.10
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: true # false

  # Forward simulation          Defaults
  use_dwa: true                 # true
  sim_time: 1.0                 # 1.7
  sim_granularity: 0.025        # 0.025
  angular_sim_granularity: 0.017 # 0.10 (1 degree = 0.017 rad)
  vx_samples: 3                 # 3
  vy_samples: 10                # 10
  vth_samples: 20               # 20

  # Scoring                     Defaults
  meter_scoring: false          # Is this even taken into account?
  path_distance_bias: 1.00      # 32.0
  goal_distance_bias: 0.10      # 24.0
  occdist_scale: 0.01           # 0.01
  forward_point_distance: 0.325 # 0.325
  stop_time_buffer: 0.20        # 0.20
  scaling_speed: 0.25           # 0.25
  max_scaling_factor: 0.20      # 0.20
  heading_lookahead: 0.325
  heading_scoring_timestep: 0.8
  heading_scoring: true         # Is this even taken into account?
  penalize_negative_x: false    # Is this even taken into account?

  # Acceleration and velocity limits

  # acc_limit_trans: 1.0
  acc_lim_x: 1.0                # 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 1.0                # 2.5
  acc_lim_theta: 1.0            # 3.2

  # max_trans_vel: 0.5
  # min_trans_vel: 0.1
  max_vel_x: +0.3
  min_vel_x: -0.3
  max_vel_y: +0.3
  min_vel_y: -0.3

  max_rot_vel: 1.0
  min_rot_vel: 0.4

  # Other                       Defaults
  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05  # 0.05
  oscillation_reset_angle: 0.20 # 0.20
  prune_plan: false             # true
  trans_stopped_vel: 0.1        # 0.1
  rot_stopped_vel: 0.1          # 0.1
  publish_cost_grid_pc: true    # false
```

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-03-05**:
Thanks @spmaniato. I do get y velocities now. However the robot keeps circling around. I tried changing the limits of velocities and acceleration. But that didnt help? Can u think of a reason for this?

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-03-05**:
I'm glad there's progress. What you're seeing might be due to some of my other parameters (tolerances, acceleration limits, etc.) I've tuned this config file for a pretty slow robot. Also, try the default scoring-related parameters. Btw, how are you localizing? AMCL? Any warnings/errors in the logs?

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-03-06**:
Thanks for the reply @spmaniato. I tried using default parameters. Yet the robot performs circular motion. I am not localizing. My sole purpose of using nav stack is obstacle avoidance. I use rolling window in global planner. I wish to give goal like (0,4),... from starting position.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-03-06**:
I see, cool. I'm guessing you've confirmed that the goal that reaches `DWAPlanner` is in the correct frame? (`/odom`). Because if the coordinate transformation is off, then the robot might be pursuing a different goal than the intended one.

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-03-16**:
@spmaniato ya I did check that. I tweaked the parameters. I am getting good results now. UAV does avoids obstacles and does reach to goal!! Thanks for the help. Here is a video of what i achieved - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1X6UWgTfsM

**Comment by [JamesDoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30501/jamesdoe/) on 2018-02-21**:
@automate Could you show the final version of your parameters? Having the same issue.